# Customise the ggplot2 legend to pick up the symbology of points not lines

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have two data frames, one gives points for drawing three lines (`rAge.df`) and one for points on which the lines are based (`rEU.df`).

```
library(ggplot2)

rAge.df<-structure(list(Age = c(35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 
                       45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 
                       35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 
                       51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 
                       41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 
                       57, 58, 59, 60), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                               2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                               3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                               3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("ND", "SD", "PV"), class = "factor"), 
               Share = c(16.4959988843349, 17.7615473921574, 19.0861268275909, 
                         20.4679657722585, 21.9047820649977, 23.3937954133475, 24.9317508644732, 
                         26.5149527816908, 28.139308544203, 29.8003807884421, 31.4934466656336, 
                         33.2135623240542, 34.9556306521092, 36.7144702485073, 38.4848836191358, 
                         40.2617227296193, 42.0399502541911, 43.8146951366457, 45.5813013960679, 
                         47.3353694462817, 49.0727895322484, 50.7897672004883, 52.4828409994153, 
                         54.1488928391191, 55.785151622991, 57.3891908941929, 51.6496034356313, 
                         49.5869357858129, 47.5118978575713, 45.4315292317247, 43.3530553560567, 
                         41.28379010844, 39.2310337902499, 37.2019694961614, 35.2035609515484, 
                         33.2424548980957, 31.3248909394419, 29.4566214415355, 27.6428436382166, 
                         25.8881455520378, 24.1964667405507, 22.5710742590061, 21.0145536304736, 
                         19.5288140682987, 18.1151067312051, 16.7740544272535, 15.5056909291712, 
                         14.3095079213272, 13.1845075612709, 12.1292586937085, 11.1419548855016, 
                         10.2204726380993, 31.8543976800338, 32.6515168220297, 33.4019753148377, 
                         34.1005049960168, 34.7421625789455, 35.3224144782125, 35.8372153452769, 
                         36.2830777221478, 36.6571305042486, 36.9571643134622, 37.1816623949245, 
                         37.3298162344103, 37.4015257096742, 37.3973841994549, 37.3186496403135, 
                         37.1672030113746, 36.9454961153352, 36.6564907950555, 36.303591872727, 
                         35.8905761264648, 35.4215195385805, 34.9007248781846, 34.3326514393138, 
                         33.7218484671724, 33.0728934915074, 32.3903364677078)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                               -78L), class = "data.frame")
rEU.df<-structure(list(MeanAge = c(48.8553004476329, 50.9208553782224, 
                           51.7996144755705, 48.3924335010784, 49.8040291699645, 51.6064465750308, 
                           44.2004512236123, 51.7996144755705, 50.8599429036558, 51.1341844537536, 
                           51.5841012929359, 51.0868375055975, 52.3291349501681, 44.3581834722897, 
                           50.125224410366, 48.9944572855644, 52.8772671501634, 46.8572780025509, 
                           49.8726702627702, 52.9016200087484, 44.5146659042334, 52.4717924092057, 
                           43.5684603465277, 50.3229230496888, 44.3581834722897, 51.4681525424742, 
                           48.9944572855644, 50.125224410366, 49.8726702627702, 52.7231809158358, 
                           49.8292117687702, 52.7231809158358, 51.0868375055975, 53.3770013131387, 
                           52.6906296509674, 48.9944572855644, 48.8553004476329, 51.6707535830708, 
                           51.6707535830708, 52.8772671501634, 51.3083721733126, 47.0454622157873, 
                           50.7131510488736, 50.8081225812258, 51.9550681604832, 53.006405791163, 
                           52.4145074733917, 48.7092245644304, 54.5400300066882, 52.2009597035923, 
                           50.4887796487131, 50.3420635400908, 55.110505120969, 48.8622481369031, 
                           51.4728114404938, 50.3420635400908, 46.6650241052098, 50.6677435091333, 
                           51.4728114404938, 52.4145074733917, 51.0868375055975, 46.8572780025509, 
                           51.5404073256315, 52.3905298999787, 50.2732415529043, 41.7969648256593, 
                           54.5400300066882, 49.8471433170061, 51.1145214426494, 52.8772671501634, 
                           44.2004512236123, 51.2619310686016, 50.8599429036558, 47.0454622157873, 
                           52.6748750541104, 50.7745528422084, 52.5012011864781, 46.3075987053115, 
                           49.8040291699645, 53.006405791163, 50.4887796487131, 53.3770013131387
), variable = structure(c(3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
                          2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
                          1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
                          2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
                          2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                          3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("ND", "SD", "PV"
                          ), class = "factor"), Share = c(27.625634115409, 32.2814072926139, 
                                                          56.384858044164, 34.7655986509275, 38.2228587954993, 47.1566923267941, 
                                                          33.1835059605237, 20.2902208201893, 31.8768659727265, 23.6260666673969, 
                                                          34.8793774319066, 15.2361775316721, 51.1094443402713, 43.3937756533486, 
                                                          18.8452733262605, 17.3539115669736, 23.4143178610931, 54.787770712593, 
                                                          26.0606348753546, 43.0121951219512, 18.2241026646866, 48.7757255936675, 
                                                          54.4961927683711, 39.7116806308526, 23.837481165896, 43.2792381233076, 
                                                          12.6050884192217, 61.6003126919426, 24.895798665589, 36.2653010926418, 
                                                          20.3900134327667, 12.4928115672153, 47.6885644768856, 18.6540198735321, 
                                                          41.1970823798627, 70.0410000138047, 31.9584258084971, 31.1343057228244, 
                                                          54.4649627548062, 27.9415690911171, 45.4125164442774, 31.0376740461905, 
                                                          20.0911195757712, 28.1058295349395, 40.2115979106705, 31.6228070175439, 
                                                          37.0480272557424, 25.9252026169319, 34.4557969971699, 41.6638098503028, 
                                                          20.6310523953056, 36.1683017825066, 44.5089389366148, 35.5591236818947, 
                                                          21.6832762379321, 42.1825341992538, 21.8815321732416, 24.6493808579052, 
                                                          30.4214678708606, 19.533282045646, 37.0752579914422, 14.7469438513339, 
                                                          20.5721956539978, 38.4446878422782, 43.7932453154804, 30.8756062393498, 
                                                          53.8110999184535, 45.3571601296126, 42.1975168384322, 48.6441130477898, 
                                                          36.8740698426061, 16.3615612873773, 45.5579762769305, 49.5034679255878, 
                                                          38.9090335803248, 56.611669632979, 47.7143668370244, 22.0682432596995, 
                                                          41.9495668700335, 17.1842105263158, 22.1445520425832, 28.3915192093097
                          )), row.names = c(178L, 60L, 75L, 174L, 190L, 4L, 134L, 158L, 
                                            225L, 166L, 61L, 98L, 30L, 32L, 151L, 82L, 99L, 218L, 89L, 53L, 
                                            159L, 3L, 156L, 179L, 115L, 70L, 165L, 68L, 172L, 25L, 175L, 
                                            108L, 181L, 164L, 194L, 248L, 95L, 58L, 224L, 182L, 23L, 84L, 
                                            85L, 90L, 37L, 55L, 243L, 223L, 207L, 33L, 212L, 229L, 200L, 
                                            155L, 103L, 63L, 54L, 154L, 20L, 160L, 15L, 135L, 162L, 183L, 
                                            47L, 5L, 41L, 209L, 211L, 16L, 51L, 101L, 59L, 167L, 67L, 240L, 
                                            48L, 119L, 24L, 138L, 129L, 247L), class = "data.frame")
```

When I produce the plot, the legend is not very meaningful. I would want it to pick up the symbology for the points data frame, not the lines, e.g. show squares, circle and triangles in the legend. Also, I'd like to provide the text of the legend, e.g. replace "ND" with "No Delay".

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data = rAge.df, aes(x = Age, y = Share, color = variable), size = 1, linetype = "dashed") + 
  geom_point(data = rEU.df, aes(x = MeanAge, y = Share, color = variable),
    size = 2, shape = as.numeric(rEU.df$variable) - 1) +
  ylim (c(0,100)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "red", "green"))+
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(0, 1, 2))
```

[image: Plot with poor legend]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `show.legend` argument to hide the lines legend and add custom labels `annotations` to the legend with the `labels` argument of the `scale_color_manual`:

```
annotations <- c("annot_1", "annot_2", "annot_3")

pl <- ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data = rAge.df, aes(x = Age, y = Share, color = variable), 
    size = 1, linetype = "dashed", show.legend = FALSE) + 
  geom_point(data = rEU.df, aes(x = MeanAge, y = Share, color = variable,
    shape = variable), size = 2) + 
  ylim (c(0,100)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "red", "green"), 
    labels = annotations) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(0, 1, 2), 
    labels = annotations)
```

[image]

Note, please, that if you want to correspond the points shape with the variable, you should include this variable into the `aes()` function. That is why I had to modify the call of the `geom_point()` function.